# Oracle: UPDATE statement causes ORA-00933 error

Tags: oracle

Can anyone see what's wrong with this statement? I've tried for a while to fix it but to no avail, and the answers I've found on the web insist I need to remove an ORDERBY statement, something I'm not using.

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE        Tags
     SET           MaskReasonId = v_MaskReasonId,
                    AppliedTime = v_AppliedTime,
                    ExpireTime = v_ExpireTime,
                    UserId = v_UserId,
                    ClientNode = v_ClientNode,
                    CommentId = v_CommentId
     FROM          Tags
     WHERE         Tag = v_sTag OR Tag = v_Tag;
END;
```

Comment: You cannot use a `join` in an update statement.

Comment: Cheers for the quick response @Ben. I've removed the `INNER JOIN` but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Did you also update your where clause after removing join.. ?

Comment: Yup, I'm now just checking `WHERE Node = v_Node;`

EDIT: Just realised I'm no longer joining that table onto this one. I've swapped over to the Tag where clause but still no joy

Comment: From tag is also not supported by oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle does not support the "FROM" construct in the update statement, try this:

```
BEGIN
   UPDATE        Tags
     SET           MaskReasonId = v_MaskReasonId,
                    AppliedTime = v_AppliedTime,
                    ExpireTime = v_ExpireTime,
                    UserId = v_UserId,
                    ClientNode = v_ClientNode,
                    CommentId = v_CommentId
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tags WHERE Tag = v_sTag OR Tag = v_Tag);
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Oracle doesn't support UPDATE FROM statement but supports UPDATE SELECT. Try this. For this query Nodes.NodeID must be a primary key in Nodes table. I guess v_MaskReasonId,... are fields from NODES(?) :

```
 update (select * from Tags
         INNER JOIN    Nodes ON Nodes.NodeId = Tags.NodeID
          WHERE         Node = v_Node AND (Tag = v_sTag OR Tag = v_Tag)
         ) t
       set t.MaskReasonId = t.v_MaskReasonId
           t.ExpireTime = t.v_ExpireTime,
           t.UserId = t.v_UserId,
           t.ClientNode = t.v_ClientNode,
           t.CommentId = t.v_CommentId
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `from tags`